# How to make links work with card-img-overlay in Bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue where any Bootstrap v4 cards using the card-img-overlay to display text over an image prevents links below that image from working.

These links do work:

```
<div class="card" style="border-color: #333;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Title image"/>
    <div class="card-inverse">
      <h1 class="text-stroke">Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <p class="card-text">Article Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Date - Author</small>
    </div>
  </div>
```

These links do NOT work:

```
<div class="card" style="border-color: #333;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Title image"/>
    <div class="card-img-overlay card-inverse">
      <h1 class="text-stroke">Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <p class="card-text">Article Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Date - Author</small>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I see there is an open issue regarding this for bootstrap v4, but can anyone help with a workaround that would preserve the same look?

Comment: You can add `position: relative` to `.card-link`

Comment: Why would you want the links to be clickable underneath the overlay though? If you want the links to be clickable, why not put them in the overlay?

Comment: Perfect, that does it.  My CSS skills are obviously lacking or I would have noticed that in the github issue opened for this.

Comment: The cards are used for articles, and I only want the article title listed in the overlay.  The links that are in the card-block below are share buttons right above the article's main text content.  The images dont always line up right with the amount of text in the article, so it seemed to look better to use the card-block below, but keep the title overlayed on the image.

Comment: Cool. Submitted as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, the explanation really helps.

Comment: awesome, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The overlay is `position: absolute` which gives that element a `z-index`, and the rest of the content in the card is statically `position`ed, so none of it has a `z-index`. You can give the link a `z-index` by adding a non-static `position`, and since your card link comes after the overlay in the HTML, the stacking order will put the card link's stacking order on top of the overlay.

```
.card-link {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Michael Coker, adding the below to your css resolves this issue.

```
.card-link {
  position: relative;
}
```